# Reporting Services Installation in SQL Server 2008 [Release] 1

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

We have the full version of SQL 2008 Server (first release) installed and licensed from download (a couple years ago).  Now we are getting into Reporting Services; however, it seems only the Express version of Reporting Services is installed.

In the  control panel under Services, I only see "SQL Reporting Services (SQLEXPRESS)" listed. [Express is ALSO on the server]

I do not think the Reporting Services option was selected when we initially installed.  I would like to go back and Change the installation, however I cannot find the SQL 2008 R1 installation disk or download.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: " SQL 2008 Server RC1" - erm, say what?! Is that licensed still?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Yeah it's an older version of SQL server. Licenses don;t expire after a couple years do they?

Comment: Yes we purchased it 2 years ago, and installed it.  Is this not normal?

Comment: OK I stand corrected. I didn't think RC1 was sold. I would seriously look at your licensing agreement and see whether it entitles you to upgrade to at least RTM

Comment: I just wanted to install Reporting Services which came with RC1, not upgrade. RS came with R1 didn't it?

Comment: Is it possible you're simply trying to make a distinction between SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 (R1, perhaps)? What does SELECT @@VERSION return?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (Intel X86)   Jul  9 2008 14:43:34   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 <X86> (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight: nicely spotted!

Comment: Moonlight, what do you mean? I was just thinking Report Serives was an option we failed to check when doing the installation, like any other feature. We just need the installaiton disk to add it (or a place to download). Or am I totally confused about something?

Comment: Perhaps I should also note that SQL Express is also on the machine, in additon to the full version.  I want to use the full version of SSRS not the express version.

Comment: @David : we were thrown by your reference to RC1 (a term used for pre-release versions that aren't sold or generally licensed for live use), but actually you seem to have the regular SQL Server 2008 as first released, ie no service packs or other patches.

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake. I meant R1. So now, on to How do I get Reporting Services running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find the original SQL Server 2008 installation media and don't have any subscriptions with Microsoft that entitle you to digital downloads of your purchased software, then I think you can try downloading the Enterprise Evaluation copy from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx) and using your existing license key for Standard in the installation process. After that, you should be able to add the Reporting Services features. Definitely backup your server before trying this, of course.

Failing that, you can install the trial version from scratch and use your license to upgrade it to the non-time-limited version (the [upgrade paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393%28SQL.100%29.aspx) allow for this).

Comment: I was unable to find that link for R1 by myself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not licence Release Candidate (RC) software for production environments or long-term use.  Instead, these are basically their version of beta software.  In a production environment, you must use RTM software.  If you check your license agreement from your initial download, you should see that you should be using the RC1 version of SQL Server 2008 only for testing.

As for how to install Reporting Services on an RTM version, unfortunately you are going to need the media.  Since you believe you have a valid license, contact Microsoft and request a copy of the media.  Once you have it, just run the setup.exe and it will allow you to modify your SQL installation to include SSRS.

Comment: poster has run @@version and determined that its not RC1

Comment: Ok, I was mistaken in saying RC1.  It's the full version of 2008 and I'm only wondering how to get Reporting Services running.